# Postgres not able to start

Tags: postgresql

I have a problem with postgres not being able to start:

```
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.5 database server                                                                              * The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
2016-08-25 04:20:53 EDT [1763-1] FATAL:  could not map anonymous shared memory: Cannot allocate memory
2016-08-25 04:20:53 EDT [1763-2] HINT:  This error usually means that PostgreSQL's request for a shared memory segment exceeded available memory, swap space, or huge pages. To reduce the request size (currently 1124007936 bytes), reduce PostgreSQL's shared memory usage, perhaps by reducing shared_buffers or max_connections.
```

This is the response that I got. I checked the log in `tail -f /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.5-main.log`and I can see the same response.

Can someone suggest what can be the problem?

I used following commands to stop/start the postgres server on Ubuntu 14.04 with postgres 9.5:

```
sudo service postgresql stop
sudo service postgresql start
```

Comment: @donkopotamus This thing happened after I have restarted postgres server without changing anything in the config. How can I allocate more memory to postgres?

Comment: Well the error message is pretty obvious isn't it? Something did change on your system and Postgres can't allocate the memory it needs. Check the config properties mentioned in the error message and adjust them.

Answer (score 0):

As other people suggested, the error was only memory. I increased droplet memory on Digital Ocean and it fixed it.